# How to make horizontal and vertical scrolling appear in browser? Overflow: auto; doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I know I can put the styles below in a CSS file, but that's for later.
Could you help with making a scrollbar appear if there's any content (red) in the `center` portion of fixed/variable width? There are situations where the User's screen might be smaller than the content, but strangely no scrollbar appears.

```
<html>
    <body>
    <div id="header" style="background: #555;margin: 0px; padding 0px; position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%;min-width: 900px; height: 50px;overflow: auto;">
    </div>

    <div id="menu" style="background: #444;margin: 0px; padding 0px; position: fixed; top: 50px; left: 0px; width: 200px; height: 100%;overflow: auto;">
    </div>

    <div id="center" style="background: #666;margin: 0px; padding 0px; position: fixed; top: 50px; left: 200px; width: 100%;min-width: 900px; height: 500px;overflow: auto;">
        <div style="width: 600px; height: 300px; background: red;overflow: auto;">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer" style="background: #777;margin: 0px; padding 0px; position: fixed; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; width: 100%;min-width: 900px; height: 50px;overflow: auto;">
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could make scrollbars appear with `html {min-width: 1100px}`, but fixed elements are not scrollable by definition.

Comment: Oh..ok. I tried with `html {min-width: 1100px}` and the scrollbar does appear, but on scrolling with it, nothing actually scrolls :-) So I guess I'd have to go back to using `relative` or `absolute`. Only problem with those is that I can't get the `footer` to start 200px from the left and then occupy the entire screen.

Comment: You can try `position: absolute`. They are scrollable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason to why your scrollbar is not showing is due to the position fixed on the **#center** div.

Heres a fiddle on what i believe you are after: http://jsfiddle.net/qgeLp1jn/

In the **#content** div, change the width of it to make the scroll bars to appear

```
#content {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
}
```